# Send id dynamically on button click xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a dynamically generated list showing an invoice number and the date of the invoice along with a "more" button which when pressed will take the user to an in depth look at an invoice.

I am struggling to determine how to bind the id and then send the id upon clicking the more button.

my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.LoggedIn">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Label x:Name="header" FontSize="25" Text="Invoices" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            />
            <ListView x:Name="BillView" ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Label YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding InvoiceNumber}" />
                                <Label YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding InvoiceDate}" />
                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="More" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Clicked="GetInvoiceDetails(HELP!!)" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Instead of clicked event, try `command` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Mvvm, you can transfer model on button click.

You can use this command to achieve it.

```
   <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="More" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Command="{ Binding BindingContext.GetIdCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=BillView} }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  />
```

Here is layout code.

```
    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <Label x:Name="header" FontSize="25" Text="Invoices" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        />
        <ListView x:Name="BillView" ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                        <Label YAlign="Center" x:Name="MyInvoiceNumber" XAlign="Center" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding InvoiceNumber}" />
                            <Label YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding InvoiceDate}" />

                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="More" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Command="{ Binding BindingContext.GetIdCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=BillView} }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyBillViewModel(Navigation);
    }
}
```

Here is `MyBillViewModel`.

```
  public class MyBillViewModel
{
    public ICommand GetIdCommand { protected set; get; }
    public ObservableCollection<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    public MyBillViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        Bills = new ObservableCollection<Bill>();
        Bills.Add(new Bill { InvoiceDate = "2020/2/23", InvoiceNumber = "1" });
        Bills.Add(new Bill { InvoiceDate = "2020/2/23", InvoiceNumber = "2" });
        Bills.Add(new Bill { InvoiceDate = "2020/2/23", InvoiceNumber = "3" });
        Bills.Add(new Bill { InvoiceDate = "2020/2/23", InvoiceNumber = "4" });
        Bills.Add(new Bill { InvoiceDate = "2020/2/23", InvoiceNumber = "5" });
        Bills.Add(new Bill { InvoiceDate = "2020/2/23", InvoiceNumber = "6" });
        Bills.Add(new Bill { InvoiceDate = "2020/2/23", InvoiceNumber = "7" });


        GetIdCommand = new Command<Bill>(async (key) => {
            Bill bill=(Bill)key;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(bill));

        });
     }
}
```

Here is `Bill` mode.

```
    public class Bill
{
    public  string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my running GIF.

[image]

I update my demo to github, you can refer to it.

https://github.com/851265601/FormsListviewCommand

Comment: Can you update your demo to github about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting command to your Button instead of Clicked event,

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference BillView}, Path=BindingContext}"   Command="{Binding YOUCOMMAND}"   CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}"></Button>
```

And for your viewmodel try this,

```
 public ICommand YOUCOMMAND
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command((e) =>
                    {
                        // Your logic
                    });
            }
        }
```

Since you've used a list view and your commands are inside the DataTemplate, the binding is attached to the binding context of the each individual model in the ItemSource.

Comment: it dont seem to be hitting the command when i place a break point

Comment: Where do you add break point? without break point is it working fine?

Comment: I am placing the break point within the YOUCOMMAND function it just never gets hit.

Comment: let me try it myself once agian