# Xamarin Firebase Database Delete Item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Product}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="lstProducts" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="13" Padding="-10" BackgroundColor="#00a8cc">
                    <StackLayout Margin="35" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ImageButton Source="uninstalling_updates_64px.png" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductId}" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="lblProductId"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductDetail}" FontSize="13" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductPrice}" FontSize="8" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <ImageButton Source="trash_48px.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="deleteButn" Clicked="deleteButn_Clicked"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have a listview here and I want to delete that record with a button I put in the listview. How can I do? thanks for your help

Comment: You can use Command for your ImageButton like this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437560/send-id-dynamically-on-button-click-xamarin, in your Command, you can execute the delete event. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/

Comment: Is that you needs?

Comment: yes definitely this thx bro

Comment: Do you achieved it in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684808/xamarin-picker-add-data-from-firebase If not, I can send you a demo about it.